# How do i track wifi connection state?

Tags: android, connection, wifi, android-wifi, wifimanager

I am making an android app which will maintain login and logout details of person using wifi connection. Person gets logged in whenever connect to WIFI and logout if connection lost.
I want to track wifi log details of android device and store in database. Is there any solution?? please help!

Comment: What exactly you want to track? I mean which wifi detail?

Answer (score 0):

Add this permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Use `BroadcastReceiver`.

```
public class WifiReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {     
    ConnectivityManager conMan = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE); 
    NetworkInfo netInfo = conMan.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (netInfo != null && netInfo.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI) 
        Log.d("WifiReceiver", "Have Wifi Connection"); // here login
    else
        Log.d("WifiReceiver", "Don't have Wifi Connection"); // here logout   
  }   
};
```

and add this in `manifest` file.

```
<receiver android:name=".WifiReceiver">
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: but how do i store login and logout details in Database? i am using phpMyadmin for my DB.

Comment: if (netInfo != null && netInfo.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI) 
        Log.d("WifiReceiver", "Have Wifi Connection"); // here login
    else
        Log.d("WifiReceiver", "Don't have Wifi Connection"); // here logout

Comment: call login and logout webservice for your phpMyadmin db.